# Why is this question opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based

(First time here, I hope I'm doing it right ;) )

It's about the original [Beauty](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64284/creature-design-is-beauty-exclusive-to-humanoid-things) question.

Why is it tagged as opinion based?

There are several definitions of beauty, e.g. at [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beauty), that sound alike:

> the quality or aggregate of qualities in a person or thing that gives pleasure to the senses or pleasurably exalts the mind or spirit

The Question asked is, in my opinion, NOT "Is xyz beautiful?", which clearly is opinion based, but "Can only humanoid things be beautiful" which is clearly not opinion based, because there are definitions of beauty. In case of human beings there are even mathematical formulae (Golden Cut, Legs to Body ration) that define beauty ([In the phi of the beholder](https://www.goldennumber.net/beauty/)).

Comment: Define what you mean by "beautiful" in your question and I think it should *then* be reopened.

Comment: I already provided two definitions, and it's not my question, I was rather curious, where the line is drawn.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, if the OP provided a definition in their question, it wouldn't be opinion based. As the choice of the definition is opinion-based, it must be in the question.

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Thanks :)

Comment: I think that even with either interpretation, the question is overly opinion-based. Even if you were to ask something extremely specific, like "Can a great horned owl be beautiful?", it would be opinion-based, because everyone interprets beauty slightly differently. I think beauty lies in planetary nebulae and the hues of smooth, worn rocks on a streambed, yet you could probably get a dozen different opinions in a question on one of those alone.

Comment: @HDE226868 I don't agree. If you ask "Can it be beautiful" the answer is yes, because can be a pleasure to see / hear. If you ask "Is it beautiful" than I agree it is opinion based.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr But from that rationale, the answer is *always* yes, because there must be at least one person who finds such a thing beautiful. In that case, is there really a point to the question?

Comment: @HDE226868 A I see you know what I mean :) Exactly, the answer is always yes, even for eldritch abominations (<= learned that here today). And that makes the question pointless (I never disagreed on that one)

Comment: "Beauty is tn the eye of the beholder" and since this question is focus on "beholder" rather than "Beauty", I think it is asking if the "beholder" could be applied to anything else beside human such as animal, alien or robot... e.g. a female hippopotamus is arose by watching the male doing explosive business therefore what the male is doing might be appealing to the female or maybe it is just my imagination...